# Concatenated SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query that builds a list of table names from the `sys.database` master table.  I then use those name in a concat statement to pull a specific piece if information out of each database.  I'm running the whole thing through a while loop to hit all tables, with a counter.

i.e.

```
set @sql = 'select top 10 * from ' + (select dbname from @table where tabid = @i + '.dbo.**tablename** where NAME = '**String Value**'
```

When I just `print` the results of `@sql`, it gives me the correct syntax, and I am able to run the command with no problem.

When I set `@sql` to `exec`, I get an error

> "database select top 10 * from **dbname** does not exist."

It's like the execute is ignoring everything after the select.

Comment: @TrippKinetics, this isn't really a sql injection problem - he's doing this all in something like SSMS.  Gregory, can you post all the relevant code?  You've only posted part of one line, it's not enough to tell what's really goingon.

Comment: @TrippKinetics He's building dynamic SQL.  You can't parameterize table names.

Comment: @DanField: It can be SQL-injectable if any of the values used in the concatenation ever originated from user input.  Regardless of where the code is executed, if a user supplied or has at any point had opportunity to change the value then it should be treated as a value and not as part of executable code.

Comment: Yes, I mean to say that I'm assuming he's doing this as an administrative task rather than one based on (non-admin) user input.  I've done such things to dynamically build up insert/create statements for example - meant for one time use when designing a procedure or something.

Comment: @GregoryWallace, you might look into the `sp_msforeachtable` function

Comment: Can you show the results you get from `print @sql`?

Comment: I tried that, but it did not include the name of the table it was pulling the information from.  I'm query around 30 or 40 tables for this information, I could try and manually determine the tables, but was hoping to make SQL get that information.

Comment: This is the query I am running:

Comment: Have you tried using `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` instead of `exec(@sql)`? I have had issues in the past where `exec(@sql)` concatenates or misreads my variable

Comment: I think you might need to escape the single quotes around 'String Value'

Comment: @Samcd select top 1 * from **dbname**.dbo.**TableName** order by **ColumnName** desc

Comment: @GregoryWallace that output is not possible from what you put in the question (i.e. no `WHERE Name=` in the output). Can you post more of your code? From the error message, it looks like it is reading this as 'select top 10 from dbname'.dbo.**TableName** and it is hard to tell why this is from the snippet that you have posted.

Comment: Also seeing where your parentheses close could be helpful

Comment: @GordonBell Here is the loop, after declaring the variables                   select top 1  from ' + (select TabName from tables where TabID = i) + ' .dbo.**Tablename** order by **ColumnName**

Comment: Note that message: "database select top 10 * from dbname does not exist." It is treating the *query* as a database reference, which can often happen if EXEC is not being called properly. Consider the emphasis: "database *SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DBNAME* does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting you're calling EXEC incorrectly.

When calling 'exec' with a T-SQL query, be sure to enclose the target string in parenthesis, eg

```
DECLARE @FOO VARCHAR(100)
Set @FOO = 'SELECT TOP 5 * from SOMETABLE'
EXEC (@FOO) -- not EXEC @FOO
```